# Does a single photon have a wavelength or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons, wavelength

I have read this question where anna v says:

> The photon is an elementary particle in the standard model of particle physics. It does not have a wavelength.

[What exactly is meant by the wavelength of a photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267034/)

And this one where Emilio Pisanty says:

> Photon frequency and wavelength are the same as the corresponding classical mode.
> If the state of the field is such that there is, whenever you look, only one excitation present, then we say the field is in a single-mode, single photon state. This photon then has a well-defined frequency (ν=ω/2π) and wavelength (λ=2π/k).

[Frequency and wavelength of photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30804/)

And if you look on this site, you find numerous occasions where people talk about the wavelength of a single photon.

[Relation between radio waves and photons generated by a classical current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443760/)

[How many wavelengths does a single photon span?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/472494/)

Naively, I would think that a photon does have energy, and frequency associated with it, and since frequency and wavelength are inversely related (in vacuum), even a single photon could have a wavelength too. But if I interpret it as a point particle defined in the standard model, then the meaning of wavelength is not so obvious.

Question:

1. Does a single photon have a wavelength or not?

Comment: write what a single photon is for me

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267034/ where @AnnaV has given the correct answer.

Comment: @my2cts as you can see Emilio Pisanty explains the opposite of that answer, and many others on this site clearly talk about the wavelength of a single photon.

Comment: @Dale I was understanding it too that way, until I read Emilio Pisanty's answer in the other link. And I read on many occasions on this site answers where people clearly talk about the wavelength of a single photon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long comment.

In the standard model of particle physics the photon is an axiomatic point particle,has spin +/-1 only , energy=hnu  , mass zero and speed the velocity of light. Wavelength is meaningless for point particles. The standard model is continuously validated as far as photon behavior goes.

After a number of discussions on similar questions I have come to the conclusion that the term "photon" as defined in particle physics, is defined differently in quantum optics, and the use of the same term to describe two different things gives rise to the confusion .

To start with, one can have many useful and mathematically consistent field theories with creation and annihilation operators operating on fields. (I first learned of field theory in a nuclear physics calculation back in 1962.)

I believe that in quantum optics, they have a field theory that describes well the classical electromagnetic wave behavior in a quantum state, as a collective photonic  field on which  excitations   , with creation and annihilation operators, are created. Those excitations they call "photons" , creating the semantic confusion.

These "photons" are composite states of the elementary particle photons, but are fundamental in their field theory, and can have a wavelength.

In this  [question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612110/is-it-possible-to-confine-a-photon-in-less-than-its-wavelength/612121#612121) and discussions, including chat, I understood the semantic difference.

In my opinion, in physics it is wrong to have the same word defining two different entities, particularly confusing  elementary particle ones of the standard model with other, very useful models in physics sub-disciplines.

All physics sub-disciplenes emerge from the elementary particle standard model and, imo, terminology should be consistent and not confusing.

Comment: This is a very helpful statement. I was thinking we were discussing about the same object in the linked question. Can you elaborate on what you mean by _"photons" are composite states_ in quantum optics? I don't know if this is still within the scope of this question, but it would also be interesting to know how the two different meanings arose. Historically photons were theoretically discovered in the blackbody spectrum as quantized excitations of field modes and in the photoeffect as particle-like objects showing localized interactions with matter.

Comment: @A.P. If the particles appearing by their creation and annihilation operators  have  a wavelength in space  these particles cannot be   elementary photons and they have to be composites of the  elementary photons  of QED on the lines given in this blog by Motl  https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html .  I am an experimental physicist so can only hand wave.

Comment: @A.P.  this use of quantum field theory is indicative https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157312002773 of what I means. . The particles created by the creation operators are called "quasi-particles" .

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: anna, any chance you could add this "comment" to your answer, at least if this question remains closed?

Comment: @stafusa do you mean the answer in the duplicate?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your remark on the inconsistent use of "photon", including the short comment on QFT are great contributions.

Comment: @stafusa  I will give a link to this answer, as otherwise  it will create a confusion, not having the context of this closed question.

Comment: Nice. That's also a good way. I was afraid this question would end up deleted if not reopened, but now [found out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238927/are-duplicates-auto-deleted) that its positive score should protect it.

Comment: @stafusa . Duplicates are not deleted, they are just not available in searches.

Comment: Actually, the help [states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) that "The system will automatically delete negatively-scored, non-migrated, unlocked, and unanswered questions (both open and closed, including as duplicates) that are older than 30 days." So not only the score, but also your answer prevent it from being automatically deleted. But, otherwise, they are deleted.

Comment: @annav Thanks for linking Motl's blog. This was a really well-written summary of quantum-classical transitions for various situations. Unfortunately neither the blog nor the linked paper really answer why quantum optic's photons should be considered quasiparticles. In the case the photon propagates through matter this is widely accepted, because its energy is distributed between the EM-field and the movement and displacement of charged particles. But for a photon in vacuum I would disagree. If the answer to this is too long I can also ask that in a separate question.

Comment: @A.P. Sorry, but I do not know whether the this photonic study works in vacuum. It is all about quantum computing and such, so it must happen in media, with fibers and conductors ..The introduction in wikipeida gives a clue that it happens in matter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonics

Comment: @annav Photonics is what I would consider the engineering branch of (quantum) optics. And sure, manipulating light only works with charged particles around. But the quantum optical concept of a photon also works in vacuum. It's probably best to formulate a question on this rather than squeezing the discussion into 500 character comments. I will do this towards the end of the week.

Comment: @A.P. I will read it with interest. Quantum Optics in wikipedia includes  the original photon discovery observations,, thats why I went to photonics.

Comment: @annav I think this answer is relevant with respect to the way quantum opticians use the term, which may not be so far from the standard model interpretation after all: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/122571/101770

Comment: This answer is **dead wrong**. There is no "semantic confusion". The term "photon" means the same thing in quantum optics as it does in QFT.

Comment: The claim "in quantum optics they have a field theory that describes well the classical electromagnetic wave behavior in a quantum state, as a collective photonic field on which excitations , with creation and annihilation operators, are created", taken literally, is correct: that field theory is QED, same as in particle physics. QED perfectly allows for single photons both with and without a well-defined wavelength. This might seem unintuitive from a *phenomenological* particle-physics perspective, but the rigorous theory trumps the phenomenological intuition; always has and always will.

Comment: Anna somehow this answer relates with my question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612110/is-it-possible-to-confine-a-photon-in-less-than-its-wavelength I do realise that the answer is something on these base. Indeed I've tried to formulated as to be difficult to be dismissed. I keep finding a lot of questions on this subject.

Comment: I even realised that the textbook explanation of the electron diffraction while clarifies the electron sides generates misconception on the photon side. In fact one can conclude that electrons propagate as wave by comparison to light. But the wave sketched would be that of light, not the wavefunction of a photon! Take this as a sort of discussion. You might further comment if you find a sense in my writing.

Comment: @Alchimista you may be interested in my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273032/what-exactly-is-a-photon/273180#273180 , this for electrons https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238855/is-it-wrong-to-say-that-an-electron-can-be-a-wave/238866#238866 and this for photons double slit  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267034/what-exactly-is-meant-by-the-wavelength-of-a-photon/267141#267141

Comment: @annav above I meant electron interference in the double slit setup, otherwise my comment seems more non sense than as it is.

Comment: And thanks for the links of course.