# Quantum meaning of classical EM field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory

The wave function of an electron has the well known statistical interpretation.

> Does the classical electromagnetic field have a similar meaning as a wave function of a photon?
> If yes, what is the precise interpretation?

A reference will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The classical EM field can be regarded as the expectation value of the quantum field in a special type of state.

In quantum electrodynamics, the electric and magnetic fields are non-commuting observables, roughly analogous to position and momentum in non-relativistic single-particle quantum mechanics. In both cases, we have an "uncertainty principle" that limits how sharply-defined their values can simultaneously be. In a state where their expectation values are large compared to their "uncertainties," the expectation values can be regarded as classical electric and magnetic fields.

My self-answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443760) gives more technical detail and more links to related posts, especially regarding the relationship between the classical EM field and the "wavefunction" of a photon.